# How to check that file content really image

Tags: java, file-type, apache-tika

To detect real file type based on file content(rather than extension) I use apache Tika.

I wrote following code:

```
    InputStream theInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\video.mp4");
    try (InputStream is = theInputStream;
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);) {
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
        Metadata md = new Metadata();
        MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(bis, md);
        mediaType.getBaseType().compareTo(MediaType))
        System.out.println(mediaType);
    }
```

this code outputs `image/jpeg`.

It is truth because I changed file extension.
Now I want to check that file is image.
I cannot find enum in MediaType class.
Now I know only the following way:

```
mediaType.toString().startsWith("image");
```

But this code looks ugly.
Can you advise nicer solution?

Comment: That's definitely the right way.

Comment: @Jason the `toString()` method of `MediaType` isn't documented in the API docs, so I wouldn't rely on that...

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that [`MediaType`](https://tika.apache.org/1.2/api/org/apache/tika/mime/MediaType.html) has a `getType()` and a `getSubtype()` method. What you are looking for is the *type* (ie. `"image/*"`). The *sub-type* in this case would be `"jpeg"`.

So your test should be:

```
if (mediaType.getType().equals("image")) {
   // Deal with image
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well AFAIK the only way to check a bit more reliable if a file is a real gif, png or whatsoever file you need to check for the unique "magic" byte sequence each of those files has.

If you are using Java 7 you could go for this solution here:
https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/transparently-improve-java-7-mime-type-recognition-with-apache-tika/

I'm not the author of this and haven't tested!